# Showing that Poisson kernel for the unit disc is harmonic.

Tags: harmonic-functions

Let $r \in [0,1)$ and $\theta \in [-\pi,\pi]$ and define,
$$P_r(\theta) =  \frac{1-r^2}{2\pi(1+r^2-2r\cos(\theta))} = \frac{1}{2\pi}\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}r^{|n|}e^{in\theta}.$$
Then I want to show that $\Delta P_r(\theta) = 0.$ 
Should I just use the fact that, 
$$\Delta f = {\frac {1}{r}}{\frac {\partial }{\partial r}}\left(r{\frac {\partial f}{\partial r}}\right)+{\frac {1}{r^{2}}}{\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial \theta ^{2}}}\\= {\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial r^{2}}}+{\frac {1}{r}}{\frac {\partial f}{\partial r}}+{\frac {1}{r^{2}}}{\frac {\partial ^{2}f}{\partial \theta ^{2}}}$$

and just compute the relevant partial derivatives using the analytic expression of $P_r(\theta)$ as follows:

$$\frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 r}\left(\frac{1-r^2}{2\pi \left(1+r^2-2r\cos \left(\theta \right)\right)}\right)+\frac{1}{r}\cdot \frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(\frac{1-r^2}{2\pi \left(1+r^2-2r\cos \left(\theta \right)\right)}\right)\\+ \frac{1}{r^2}\cdot \frac{\partial^2}{\partial^2 \theta }\left(\frac{1-r^2}{2\pi \left(1+r^2-2r\cos \left(\theta \right)\right)}\right) \\=\frac{4\left(\cos ^2\left(θ\right)+\sin ^2\left(θ\right)-r^2\cos ^2\left(θ\right)-r^2\sin ^2\left(θ\right)+r^2-1\right)}{\pi \left(r^2-2r\cos \left(θ\right)+1\right)^3}\\=0?$$

Also, should I consider the case $r=0$ separately?

Answer (score 3):

That will work eventually, but it's easier to apply $\Delta$ to each $r^{\left|n\right|}\exp{in\theta}$ term. Note in particular the $r$ derivatives multiply by $n^2$ (the first expression for $\Delta$ gets this faster), while the $\theta$ sector multiplies by $-n^2$.

Comment: But you have to justify differentiating the infinite series. How do you propose to do that?

Comment: @model_checker $\partial_z f(z)$ [has the same radius of convergence](http://people.reed.edu/~mayer/math112.html/html2/node35.html) as $f(z)$. The proof is [very technical](http://people.reed.edu/~mayer/math112.html/html2/node40.html#difffpff). You can use the same techniques to address Laplacians of complex functions. This is worth knowing; but if such material is currently unfamiliar, you should probably just augment your existing strategy with user657324's observation.

Answer (score 0):

Acctually, your calculation is fine :

use
$$\cos^2(\theta )+\sin^2(\theta )=1$$
$$-r^2\cos^2(\theta )-r^2\sin^2(\theta )=-r^2,$$
and conclude.